# Difference Environment.StackTrace and Exception.ToString() in C#?

Tags: c#, exception, logging, stack-trace

How to get the StackTrace similar to `Exception.ToString()`?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6624522/647845) it should be `Environment.StackTrace` - but I get different results for both methods.

Below is a simplified example. I have seen cases with `Environment.StackTrace` having **+160 lines more** then `Exception.ToString()`.

These lines seems to be mainly underlying framework things like related to tasks etc, and I'm in no need for them.

Is it possible to get the exact same formatting as `Exception.ToString()`?

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await Task.Delay(0);

            string fromStackTrace   = Environment.StackTrace;
            string fromException;

            try
            {
                throw new Exception("Test");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                fromException = e.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result **fromException**:

```
System.Exception: Test
   at ConsoleApp2.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Temp\C#\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs:line 17
```

Result **fromStackTrace**:

```
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at ConsoleApp2.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Temp\C#\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs:line 12
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at ConsoleApp2.Program.Main(String[] args)
   at ConsoleApp2.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

Comment: Exception in `catch` is [unwinded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Unwinding), that's why it's shorter, because it finds handler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.Net - what is an "unwind"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005606/net-what-is-an-unwind)